# not set focus on element

Tags: javascript, asp.net

If to log out and press F5 several times focus don't set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var logonField = document.getElementById('UserName');

                if (logonField) {
                    logonField.focus();
                    logonField.click();
                }
            }, 200);
        });
    </script>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "logonField", style = "width:100px;"})%><br/>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
```

Comment: To confirm, the element UserName will always be true or false?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: js code just cushed. After clean cash, all work. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user simple Java script which will call on

> on load event 
>   of html body.